# How to detach Postgres attachment from Heroku app?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm cleaning up some ops stuff on a Rails app hosted on Heroku and noticed we have two postgres attachments set up which means we are paying double. I dug into the tables and saw that one (`HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE`) is out of date and apparently not currently being used while another is set up as `DATABASE` and does have up to date data.

Being the careful person I am, after creating manual backups of both DBs, I went to simply detach the WHITE (unused) DB rather than delete. But Heroku won't let me. The detach button is disabled in the dashboard and via the CLI I'm told `Cannot destroy last attachment to billing app for resource`. So I tried promoting the other DB and was told `postgresql-octagonal-xxxxx is already promoted`. Furthermore, this DB *does* appear to be detachable via the dashboard.

So why is the DB that *is* being used detachable and the one that *isn't* not detachable? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is, the database is attached *only* to that app, so if you detach it, where will it exist? You would have a Postgres resource attached to no apps so therefore would not be able to see it.

Reading [this page](https://help.heroku.com/F3FDA7AC/why-am-i-unable-to-remove-addons-using-addons-detach-from-my-application), it seems that you should just delete the resource rather than trying to detach it from the last app it’s attached to.